# Cisco ASA Licensing Upgrade Paths

Tags: cisco-asa

I have the following questions: I'm currently managing several 5512-X units running Security Plus License (several different units paired in Active / Standby failover configuration for several server stacks).

The units are all running on a 9.1(7) OS vers. Recently we purchased a unit running os. 9.4(6). I was wondering if it would be possible to upgrade the ASA 5512-X units running the 9.1(7) OS vers. to the ASA os vers. 9.4(6) and retaining the functionalities sets enabled under the currently installed Security Plus license (that is, without having to purchase a new "Security Plus" license).

Comment: Do you have SMARTnet licenses for each device?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of any licensing entitlement changes between 9.1 and 9.4. In general, whatever features were licensed in one version will still be available in later versions. (i.e. you don't need a new activation code)

Moving to a newer release without SmartNet (or Cisco TAC explicitly providing the image) would be a violation of numerous licensing conditions.